# Does Herobrine exist?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen videos of a mob named Herobrine being summoned or randomly encountered. He has the default Minecraft skin but with glowing white eyes. Are these videos all hoaxes or is there a way to summon Herobrine in Minecraft survival mode without mods? Can he be randomly encountered?

Comment: What is Herobrine?

Comment: Or who is Herobrine. My mistake I didn't explain, added a description for you.

Comment: Alltough herobrine does not exist, There seem to be plans of random abandoned ruins/city's

Comment: Brick Pyramids used to show up in the past as well.

Comment: @Raven What is Herobrine, might make for a interesting question.

Comment: @Arkive - Yeah, I googled it. It's very simple; it's a hoax.

Comment: It's a very dumb hoax, I can't believe anyone would actually be creeped out by it.

Comment: I think there might be a few mods that spawn in hero brine. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: Related meta post: [What should we do with clearly fake questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14616/4797)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we only accept [real questions about problems relating to gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14616/4797). (related meta post linked)

Comment: I don't think it exists. However, you can summon it using mods

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Notch on Twitter is pretty clear on the topic:

> I have no plans of adding herobrine.
>
> <sub>[Notch](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/statuses/27871748827)</sub>

Comment: That's disappointing. He could've been a real neat feature in the game, building random pyramids and haunting players.

Comment: Thank god, personally. It'd creep me out way too much and I'd probably never play again. The game can be unsettling enough in caves alone at night. :(

Comment: @Sadly Not: [Here's a good read about the whole hoax](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/User:Kizzycocoa/Herobrine).

Comment: @Bobby: Thanks for the link :) that could almost be appropriate for an answer but I think @badp has it.

Comment: Plot twist: It is already in xD
Well....the thing is, that such a thing is POSSIBLE by technical meanings just now, you just need some AI , everything else the game has. However it would have to be hidden really deep in code, so I doubt it is here because we quite know the MC code and such a thing wouldn't hide for so long.

Answer (score 22):

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer: NO.

And he "removed" him in the 1.6.6 update.

Comment: and _again_ in [1.7](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/7080851021/minecraft-beta-1-7)

Comment: notch said he removed him just to scare people.

Comment: @Zommuter and again in 1.8

Comment: And probably again in 1.9

Comment: He says re removed him in the 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, and 1.8 updates, as well as 1.1.

Comment: Dude you just said no 2 times.

Comment: This is added to literally every patch note, it was a joke that may have gone a bit far.

Comment: The patch note changes was for reaffirming he does not exist. Now, the load screen tip on the Xbox 360 that suggests he was added during the port to that console is a joke too far.

Answer (score 18):

No. While modding I must have seen every source file since Alpha 1.0_17 a couple of times, and there's simply nothing there. Unless he's an emergent feature of the deepest bowels of the rendering code.

Answer (score 7):

## Is Herobrine Real?

No, Herobrine doesn't exist, despite the fact he was seen by other player and have evidence that he was real. Notch says he wasn't real. Something like this:

> Herobrine isn't real. He was just one of the creepypastas that people made up.

Some say he was Notch's dead brother. But he has no brother. Neither did he have any other brothers. Of course, if Notch really did prove to add him, he would of got fired and he would lose all his money since he was a billionare. There is a Herobrine mod, but the sightings on the game without mods were different than the mods itself. Of course the Wiki says:

> - Herobrine is not in Minecraft.
> - There are no references to him at all in the source code, and there is no code to allow for any entity to act like Herobrine. There is no level terrain code to generate redstone torches, 2x2 tunnels or elaborate dungeons with traps.
> - There is no possible way Herobrine can ever exist in any unmodded clients or servers. Any claims that he is in Minecraft are completely false. Any appearances he may have are caused by mods being installed.

## What does Notch say about Herobrine?

Notch tweeted:

> Herobrine isn't real in any way, no. I never had a brother (well, there's a half brother I never meet..), and he's not in the game.
>
> Getting loads of tweets and emails about Herobrine again. I don't have a dead brother, and he never was in the game. Not real. Never was.
>
> The Herobrine stuff is awesome and kind of scary at the same time. It really shows how little control a content producer has over the content.
>
> I've publicly told people there's never been any such thing as Herobrine, and that I don't have any dead brothers, and that letting too many animals die in lava is a fool proof way to summon him but that you don't need to be afraid of him. He only means well, he's looking out for you, trying to warn you of the dangers you can't see. There certainly are NO physical manifestations of Herobrine that will sneak out of your computer if you leave Minecraft running at night, looming over you as you sleep with his pale eyes inches away from your face, as he tries to shout at you to wake up. Sometimes you wake up with a jolt, and he's gone, and all that lingers is the memory and faint echo of his wordless screaming. Of course it was just a dream. There's no way a morally dubious ghost with a god complex could at any point decide to haunt the children who play my game "for their own good", as there is NO SUCH THING. etc etc
>
> Also herobrine is not real please stop asking argh

So of course, we have no evidence that he is in the game and is Notch lying? Or did someone really put a joke? We don't know.

Also when ever some people tweet him about Herobrine, he says:

> I have no plans of adding herobrine.

## Updates

Most of updates that Minecraft had normally say:

> - Removed Herobrine

This made people think Herobrine was in the game and that he was removed. However, that was a joke from Notch, just so he could get rid of the Herobrine Argument.

Answer (score 6):

He is not real. Legends say he is the ghost of Notch's brother, and he will not stop at anything to kill you, but he doesn't exist. The many videos that say he does are fake.

Besides, every update they have a "Removed Herobrine" thing.

Trust me, he is nothing to be frightened of.

Answer (score 2):

Here, hate to break the fact, I checked every resource as a programmer, there is no thing in Minecraft that has 'Herobrine' it exits a long time ago when they had servers and some hacker decided to do some trolling. Notch also indicated "I have no intention to add Herobrine" Neither does Jeb, with Microsoft's move to buy Minecraft, they would have realized that there was Herobrine. Probably someone mistakenly thought the 'Giant Zombie' was Herobrine. Might had been a development error for the giant zombie.

The reason people say that they have seen herobrine and those videos were to start a haux rumor around Minecraft. Also known as ** THEY USED SOME TEXTURE PACK THAT MADE IT SEEM LIKE THERE WAS HEROBRINE**

Long story short- **NO HE DOES NOT EXIST**

Answer (score 1):

Herobrine does not exist. It is some video editing, Photoshop or maybe texture packs that's trying to trick you.

*Play those singleplayer worlds without fear!* Don't be afraid.