# What is (or rather, was) Herobrine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm pretty sure this line's main purpose in the [version 1.6.6 changelog](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/6035819427/minecraft-beta-1-6-6) is to mess with us, but still, it's there:

> - Removed Herobrine

[Curse's Minecraft Wiki does no longer want to host information about it](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Herobrine), so — **what is this Herobrine thing** that would have been removed?

(Also see this question asking [whether or not it's ever been *added* in the first place.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18592/23))

Comment: Someone needs to make a list of best excerpts from real patch notes. (Though I think Dwarf Fortress may need to be limited to only one note)

Comment: @Raven; Though you may have to differentiate between best **real** patch notes (Like `Fixed the size of the moon` or... yeah, I'm sure you can find something from every major DF release) and best fakes, like this one.

Comment: The "Removed Herobrine" sentence from the changelog is multiply inserted in it. When there is a new version (the ones like 1.7 or 1.8) the thing with Herobrine appears. I looked some time ago in a large changelog (that included betas)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Herobrine was a fictional character that was said to 'haunt' Minecraft. People would fake screenshots saying he followed them into caves or whatever. He was said to be Notch's dead brother (who doesn't exist).

[image]

With the mod that allows you to bring fake NPCs into the game, it became more common to put fake Herobrines into the game.

He does not exist and is a joke. This was Notch's response - trolling.

There is a ton of backstory and stuff [here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/herobrine).

Answer (score 9):

Quick repost of the original source of Herobrine, from the link @Communist Duck provided (in case that link ever goes down):

[image: Herobrine]

Comment: That's not Herobrine, that's a chicken. :P

Comment: Look closer! Or maybe you don't want to get so close... :P

Comment: I'm tempted to enhance this image with freehand circles.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck Herobrine is on the left side of the chicken next to the hill.

Answer (score 7):

Herobrine was and is an joke.

It was made by re-skinning some textures, and was a story people made up to go along with it.

I assume Notch said he removed it because the whole of Mojang seem to be trolls.

Comment: Trolls *are* originally Scandinavian.

Answer (score 4):

The wiki site is still here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/User:Kizzycocoa/Herobrine