# Has 'Herobrine' ever been in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is (or rather, was) Herobrine?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23669/what-is-or-rather-was-herobrine)
>   [Does herobrine exist?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18592/does-herobrine-exist)

On the Minecraft launcher start screen (just after you launch the game) it says 1.3.1

- Single-player now runs a server internally

and some more stuff, but at the bottom it says

- removed Herobrine.

Is that true?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. At no point has Herobrine been a part of Minecraft. It is a running gag to have Herobrine removed every couple of revisions.

Comment: @RustyMember Who are you calling an [alot](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_D_Z-D2tzi14/S8TRIo4br3I/AAAAAAAACv4/Zh7_GcMlRKo/s400/ALOT.png)? :-P

Comment: Gag? Oh, it's no gag. They keep removing him, but he finds his way back in...