# Are the birds in Minecraft chickens or ducks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I can't decide; are the egg-laying birds in Minecraft chickens or ducks?

[image: Chicken?][image: Or duck?]

Comment: My first reaction is "What?" My second is, is this really one of the ["practical ... questions based on actual problems that you face"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: How is this not a valid question?  It relates to "Game mechanics and **terminology**".  It is practical in the sense that knowing game terminology is helpful for discussing it, if not necessarily playing it in this case.  It also has a concrete answer.  Reopen?

Comment: @Ben Blank - because it is not so much a question as a rhetorical memetic question, recently driven to popularity by Notch himself. I'm more inclined to re-close it as "not-constructive".

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — I would disagree.  I've seen discussions on the forum debating this very question and it's evidently significant enough a confusion to warrant mention on the wiki page.  Both many months before Notch's recent post.  This question seems to me largely equivalent to [Does Herobrine exist?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18592/does-herobrine-exist).

Comment: if you closed my question then shouldn't the Does herobrine exist? question be closed too?

Comment: those are chickens

Comment: I wouldn't mind reopening it if it was phrased like a normal question, but I'm agreeing with Raven as it is now.

Comment: @BenBlank Does Herobrine exist? has a quantifiable answer. Does this question?

Comment: @ArdaXi: Yes, they are chickens.

Comment: @Ullallulloo If that can be backed up, this question should be re-opened.

Comment: @ArdaXi: They have crops, Notch, Jeb, and the Minecraft wiki refer to them as chickens, and in 1.8, they'll drop an item called "Raw Chicken".

Comment: The real question is: Which came first, the Chicken, or the Duck Egg?

Comment: @Arda Xi — Yes.  Just as with Herobrine, this can be determined by examining the source.

Comment: @Arda Xi — In the source, all of the chicken's sounds are identified as `"mob.chicken<sound>"`.  These are stored as ordinary strings and are not obfuscated — you can check it yourself by cracking open `minecraft.jar` and examining `ww.class`.  You should see `mob.chicken`, `mob.chickenhurt`, etc.  For that matter, the texture file is named `chicken.png`…

Comment: @BenBlank I can name a file `unicorn.png` and it could still be a horse. If it is intentionally left ambiguous by Notch, he could go ahead and say it's a duck despite the name.

Comment: @Arda Xi — By that argument, you could say that the cows are shaved bison and the pigs are stunted giraffes.  To corrupt a phrase, if it's named a chicken and has the anatomy of a chicken, it's a chicken.

Comment: @BenBlank: Plus, they go cluck, and in 1.8, they'll drop an item called "Raw Chicken", you should just go ahead an answer. Feel free to use what I said.

Comment: @BenBlank If it's named a chicken and it has ambiguous anatomy, it is whatever Notch says it is. If Notch later calls it a duck, it's a duck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are chickens.  This can be verified in the source code, where the sounds they make are all identified as `mob.chicken` and the skin texture is `chicken.png`.  Additionally, you can see their [wattles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wattle_%28anatomy%29) in-game, which ducks do not have.

It has been mentioned that, in a recent blog post, Notch himself [expressed some confusion](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/9896830082/you-know-whats-fun) over their species.  As he is the one who *created* them, however, this is likely an in-joke for the community — he has a history of such humor, like the [patch note for removing Herobrine](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/6035819427/minecraft-beta-1-6-6).

***Update:*** Notch [tweeted today](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/129820154359062528) that "the chicken is now a duck".  It's unclear whether this is a change in direction… or more trolling.

Comment: +1 especially for explaining the contribution of our favourite Swedish troll to the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

As pictured in the question, creature has a red piece of body unterneath beak. It's quite similar in placement and color to an organ named the [wattle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wattle_%28anatomy%29) which distinguishes Chickens (Gallus Gallus Domesticus) from Ducks (Anatidae).

Answer (score 3):

I think that they are chickens because in the minecraft wiki, it says that they are chicken.

[Minecraft Wiki Mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs)
[image: Picture]